# Python. Бинарное дерево, наследование класса, принадлежность объекта классу предка

Tags: python, ооп, классы, наследование, бинарное-дерево

Имеется бинарное дерево. Пр попытке наследования класса - дочерние узлы не принадлежат классу NewNode. Как решить эту проблему?

```
    class Node:
    def __init__(self, key=None):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


    def insert(self, key):
        if self.key is None:
            self.key = key
            return

        if key < self.key:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(key)
            else:
                self.left.insert(key)
        elif key > self.key:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(key)
            else:
                self.right.insert(key)
        else:
            return


class NewNode(Node):
    pass


def test_liskov_substitution():

    tree = NewNode()
    tree.insert(5)
    tree.insert(3)
    tree.insert(7)

    assert isinstance(tree.left, NewNode), "Sibling should be NewNode too"
    assert isinstance(tree.right, NewNode), "Sibling should be NewNode too"


tree = NewNode()
tree.insert(5)
print(tree.key)
tree.insert(8)
print(tree.right.key)
tree.insert(3)
print(tree.left.key)
test_liskov_substitution()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда создаёте новый экземпляр класса, вместо явного вызова `Node()` получите имя класса из переменной `self.__class__` и используйте его.
Т.е., к примеру, вместо:

```
self.left = Node(key)
```

пишите так:

```
self.left = self.__class__(key)
```

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку!

Answer (score 1):

Наследование работает прекрасно.
Ваше `tree.insert(8)` сохраняется не в `left`, а в `right`.
Вы же написали

```
        elif key > self.key:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(key)
            else:
                self.right.insert(key)
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, неправильно описал проблему. Задача - добиться соответсвия дочерних узлов классу-потомку.